# Is there a way to refresh android WebView in background service?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I want to know whether it is possible to load url in background?
overall i want to achieve is that to refresh some url in background using Java android.

Comment: elaborate more, post some code. it is possible for shure

Comment: @snachmsm in normal android webview to load webpage you get reference to webview of xml by findViewById(R.id.webview) then you call load method. But in background service i've no xml view so how shall i load the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `Service` [bind](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) to `Activity` and send [message](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) forcing `WebView` refresh or load your URL which may be passed through binder

you haven't posted single line of code so this is most precise answer you can get...

Comment: thanks. I want link get loaded or refreshed using your suggested method by binding service to activity will it work even app is closed ?

Comment: no, `WebView` is a `View` obviously, so it handle its content only when it is visible on the screen